# How do relpol RM84-2012-25 relays work?

Tags: switches, relay

Again, I am asking noob question because I have no background in electronics. In some installation that I am trying to understand there are those kind of relays, use as a logic for buttons (switches):

[image: relpol RM84-2012-25 relays]

I read the manual of relpol, and although I know how relays generally work, I don't quite understand the logic behind it. Can someone kindly explain?

Edit: Just to clarify, I don't understand which wire corresponds to which number on circuit e.i 22,12,24,14 and etc while on the circuit there are 1-2(coils), 4-7 commons and 3 5 7 normally open.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a nine page [manual](https://www.tme.eu/en/Document/03db36903fbbe089c5f2033cc05648eb/e_RM84.pdf) Do you expect us to read it to you word for word..... Ask what you do not understand.

Comment: Energize the coil to close the normally open contacts and open the normally closed contacts. Done.  =-D

Comment: *because I have no background in electronics*  *I don't quite understand the logic behind it* Then I don't see **why** you would need to know or even **can know** the "logic" behind it. What purpose would this "understanding the logic" serve if you have no background in electronics? If you don't understand electronics I don't see the point in figuring out these relays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is shown in the [datasheet](http://relpol.bg/catalogs/RELPOL/Miniature/RM84.pdf).

[image]

*Figure 1. Relay pinout with alternate numbering systems.*

You can be forgiven for being confused if just looking at the relays. (Forgiveness for not reading the datasheet would be different.)

The relays in your shaky photo show the pinout using the numbers 1 to 8. These are shown in parentheses on the pinout diagram.

The relay bases may be from a different manufacturer and show the European contact numbering scheme on them.

- A1: DC+
- A2: DC-
- 11 to 12: Normally closed contact 1.
- 21 to 22: Normally closed contact 2.

The standard would use

- 13 to 14: Normally open contact 1.
- 23 to 24: Normally open contact 2.

but in this case the contacts are changeover type so

- 11 to 14: Normally open contact 1.
- 21 to 24: Normally open contact 2.

---

How it works:

- When the coil is de-energised contacts 11-12 and 21-22 are closed.
- When the coil is energised contacts 11-14 and 21-24 are closed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it is clear what happens there.  I am really new to electronics and was just confused.